# Mobile Redirect from specific page / QR Code

Tags: redirect, mobile

My client has created a QR Code that goes to a specific page on her non-mobile site.
She does have a mobile site, m.customersdomain.com

Question is, the QR Code has already been submitted to print for advertising and is going to a regular URL like:
http://www.customerdomain.com/specificpage

Is there a way to look for mobile devices that hit this one non-mobile page and redirect them to a mobile URL / page with the same content?

Answer (score 0):

You must add some code to your customer's server in order to detect whether the hit comes from a mobile device and redirect accordingly.

Here you can get examples of how to make that detection on several programming languages:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: Jorge,

Have this so far for JS:

if ((screen.width <= 700) && 
currentpage("http://customersite.com/gotopage")) {
 window.location = "http://m.customersite.com/gotopage";
 }

I just need to figure out how to look @ the current URL, and if it is in fact http://customersite.com/gotopage, then send them via window.location to http://m.customersite.com/gotopage

Comment: All,

This may do it:

if ((screen.width <= 700) &&
location.href("regularURL")) {
window.location = "mobileurl";
}

...maybe???

Any better way?

Thanks!